# Oracle Forms Dynamic LOV

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracleforms

I'm working with 2 LOV's for my form. One is a regular LOV and the other is a dynamic LOV. Cannot figure out how to clear the dependent LOV.

for example my first LOV I have:

```
select job_id, job_name from jobs
```

and my second LOV is:

```
select employee_id, employee_name from employees where job_id = :job_block.job_id
```

I select the job_id and job_name from the first LOV and then I choose the corresponding employee_id and employee_name from the second LOV.

Now if I go back and pick a new Job_id from the first LOV, is there a way I can clear out the employee selection automatically from the first time around?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can clear employee items on WHEN-VALIDATE-ITEM on JOB_ID item.

I would recomend other solution - forms provides for dependent items validation WHEN-VALIDATE-RECORD trigger. Let user change job_id although you have set employee items already and validate their dependendy on record level. Show to the user an alert if job an employee items doesn't fit.

Comment: I ended up trying your second solution and it worked great. Thank you.